# How to setup/hide Stripe Secret API Key in Ionic Project?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, stripe-payments, secret-key

It's a quick/simple question I cannot find the answer to. How to I hide my secret Stripe API key in an ionic project?

Comment: you don't... it needs to stay on a server for safety

Comment: So I would have to create a server side endpoint that had my secret key that my client calls and my server would make a call to the stripe server to process the actual payment? Is there a less of a headache method? I thought stripe was more or less a quick/painless method?

Comment: you can use javascript sdk to get a token using public key, then when that comes back send it to your server to make the actual charge

Comment: That still needs to be done over SSL though right? How can I do that in an ionic app?

Comment: you could, but there is not much anyone can do with the token. It will only be recognized when matched with your secret key when server sends it to stripe. The credit card is not transmitted to server, just the token and other specifics about the charge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like others here have said. You Don't.

If you want to process payments in an ionic app you need your private key on a server and can use the public key in the app.

You will likely need to send the user info to a server that you make where the server will actually make the reqest to stripe to process the payment.

One recomendation would be to create a parse.com account and have Parse Cloud Code process the stripe payment. This is what it would look like.

**Parse Cloud Code**

```
    var Stripe = require('stripe');
Stripe.initialize('sk_test_xxx');

Parse.Cloud.define("purchaseItem", function(request, response) {...
```

**ionic**

```
Parse.Cloud.run ("purchaseItem" ....
```

Answer (score -3):

You can do this by hiding the API key in native java code. Because it will be compiled to binary data. Then create a javascript interface to call that native function to get the secret key through cordova plugin feature.

For creating plugin: [This article](https://blogs.oracle.com/mobile/entry/introduction_to_custom_cordova_plugin) may help you.

Comment: you should never include the secret api key on a client side application, even if its compiled to binary, it can easily be inspected and found.